# April Hokkaido Camping and Hiking

Tags: camping, hiking, hokkaido

I want to spend 4-5 days in early april camping and hiking(1 or 2 multi-day hikes, not many single day hiking) in Hokkaido..

I understand that it will be cold, and snow will still be on the ground. I had no problems with both. Just need some overnight trails to hike.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I think this question belongs better on [Outdoors.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might belong more on [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/).